# Modifying data frames with Shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I have a data frame that I would like to cycle through and manually edit. The idea is to look up similar values in another frame and then choose the "best" answer to enter. For example if df1 is:

```
Desc               common    code
Slept well         sleep
Ate breakfast      eat
Went for running   exercise
Afternoon nap      sleep
Sleeping well      sleep
...
```

and df2 is

```
common     Desc               code
sleep      Overnight sleep    0001
sleep      daytime sleep      0002
eat        Breakfast          0010
eat        Morning snack      0020
...
```

I'd like to display each Desc from df1 and then the list of all items matching "common" in df2 for selecting. When I select the "best" match, then I want to go to the next row of df1 and continue on.

Does anyone have some example code for this or ideas on how it could be done?

Comment: before playing around with Shiny, try to solve you problem using base R. Look into %in% operator and ?intersect

Comment: I could do it using base R as you suggest if there wasn't the need for manual inspection. For example, the "sleep" items (i.e. "Slept well", "Afternoon nap", "Sleeping well") are manually entered and not easy to automate to the codes. That's why I want to display them and cycle through asking user for input. Shiny seems a nice interface.